# Covid restrictions based on originating or connecting locations?

Tags: transit, international-travel, covid-19, connecting-flights, morocco

In the case of a flight originating in a place with one set of restrictions imposed by the destination country, but connecting on the same airline through a country with more restrictive rules, is there a general rule as to whether the more restrictive rules will be applied?

I’m specifically interested in Canada to Morocco via Portugal- after Morocco re-opens to international arrivals, hopefully early next month. Morocco has Canada on List A but Portugal on List B, which seems without much basis, but that is their current rule for what I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a general rule as to whether the more restrictive rules will be applied?

No, that depends on the policy of the final destination country. Some care about countries you've transited through, some don't. Most don't care. Countries may change their policies anytime.

E.g. Morocco currently [cares](https://ma.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220109004844/https://ma.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/)):

> Travelers from List B countries, which includes those simply transiting a List B country, must be fully vaccinated AND present a negative PCR test administered within 48 hours of the date entering Morocco
>
> [...] Unvaccinated or incompletely vaccinated travelers from countries on List B must undergo a 10-day quarantine on arrival at a hotel.  Please see the “Country Specific-Information” section above.

Comment: Interesting. The main worry is the quarantine requirement rather than the test requirement and the US State Dept. website does not address that., but it certainly supports your statement that it may matter.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany https://archive.ph/2Ogfu#selection-2071.219-2071.341 "If not fully vaccinated, travelers coming from or transiting List B countries must undergo a 10-day quarantine on arrival." May have changed since then though. But likely not.

Comment: Ah, beans. Thanks

Comment: In my case (Finland-Australia, with the transit in Singapore) the airline did care about the more restrictive rules of Singapore (concerning the time period when a PCR test should be performed). It caused issues with the boarding of some passengers.

Comment: @colombien some countries indeed have transit covid rules. What a mess. It's a question different from the OP's question though.